# Nautilus not working since 16.04 install

Tags: nautilus, gtk, glib

So after I installed 16.04 Ubuntu update, I tried to open my home folder, but it didn't work. I tried running `nautilus` in terminal and it thrown this:

```
user@user-desktop:~$ nautilus

(nautilus:13623): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **:
g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed

(nautilus:13623): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **:
g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed
Neizdevās reģistrēt lietotni: Iestājās noildze

(nautilus:13623): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(nautilus:13623): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(nautilus:13623): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
```

The `Neizdevās reģistrēt lietotni: Iestājās noildze` means `Failed to register application: delay`. I have no idea what's going on, but what I care more is how to solve this.

By the way, the nautilus opens fine when I run it through gksudo(`gksudo nautilus`).

Comment: Is everything in your home ~ folder owned by you?  You can try `sudo chown -R username:username /home/username`

Comment: What does that do? Yes, I own everything(except few files which are root-only, but they should have nothing to do with this as they're printer-releated).

Comment: Technically, everything in your home folder should belong to your username.   That command you replace username with your login name and it will go through and put everything in that folder to your username.  The only reason why I suggest that is that you claim that running `gksudo nautilus` is running it as the elevated user.  From what I have seen in the past, that means that something about `nautilus` that it is trying to open in a configuration or something is not owned by you.

Comment: could you ad the output of `ls -la ~` - might help sorting out the permissions idea.

Comment: Have you tested in other user? If works, could be a solution, create another user, and transfer config /home files to this one, except nautilus config.

Comment: Hi! This issue had gone after single reboot. I forgot to mention before...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same symptoms as above.

Nautilus would not open as my own user.
Nautilus would open fine using gksudo nautilus.

I opened a terminal to run as my own user, and got very similar error messages as above.

This link solved the problem for me:

[Nautilus not opening up, showing GLib error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/788182/nautilus-not-opening-up-showing-glib-error)

Here is the gist of the problem:

- Some nautilus processes were still running that need to be killed.

The linked solution describes how to find the process ID's and kill them.

After that, I am fine - no need to reboot or anything.

Comment: Please don't post link only answers.  Include the essential parts of the article instead.

Comment: I added some more detail after your comment, but this was the essential part of the article as per my original post: _"Some nautilus processes were still running that need to be killed."_

Comment: @jokerdino _"seemingly went away on its own or was only relevant to a very specific period of time"_ <- A reboot would have made the problem go away as the errant processes would be killed on shut-down. The article I linked to was however helpful as I didn't need to close all of my apps and restart.

Comment: Thanks, @TaoRich, that's at least somewhat better.  It would have been even better, however, to flag as a duplicate.

Comment: You're not actually giving the solution, just a link to it. Since it's also an AskUbuntu page, it would have been better to flag as a dupe.

Comment: @Zacharee1 - Cool, understood for future. If I click [flag] now, I can't see the **duplicate** option ... is that because (1) the question is on hold, or (2) I do not have enough rep to flag as duplicate, and need to instead flag as **in need of moderator intervention** ?

Comment: @TaoRich you can't flag to close something that's already closed, so that's why it doesn't show up.

Comment: @TaoRich i think we have conflated two issues , one of locked of hidden nautilus process and another of these glib errors , i had nautilus fail to start and also had those messages. They where still emitted  after i got nautilus running  properly again so it would seem they are from another cause. Its easily done because the scope of the critical error message isn't implied so it seems global but obviously isnt as other things happen after it. running nautilus in a terminal should also yield the same messages each time. It might just be a detection routine being too noisy.

Comment: @Amias : agreed. My nautilus is running fine now, and I just started it in a terminal, and get the same errors as per the OP.