# Nautilus not opening up, showing GLib error

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, glib

When I launch nautilus from terminal the following error is printed and nautilus doesn't open up.

```
(nautilus:25179): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed

(nautilus:25179): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed
Could not register the application: Timeout was reached

(nautilus:25179): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(nautilus:25179): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(nautilus:25179): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
```

What could be the problem??

Answer (score 73, accepted):

This answer by [cortopy](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/users/15238/cortopy/) in [ask.fedoraproject.org](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/72155/nautilus-critical-error/), worked for me.

> I've been experiencing a similar problem today, only I couldn't open
>   nautilus at all. So I'm wondering if this is due to some recent update
>   clash.
>
> This isn't a likely solution, but at least it allows me to carry on as
>   normal.
>
> First thing to try is `sudo nautilus` in a terminal. If it works, then
>   it may mean that there is something wrong with active nautilus
>   processess for your current user.
>
> To be able to restart nautilus properly, do the following:
>
> 1. See what nautilus processes are running :
>
>    ```
>    ps aux | grep nautilus
>    ```
> 2. Kill all nautilus processes you see :
>
>    ```
>    sudo kill PIDNUMBER
>    ```
> 3. Restart nautilus :
>
>    ```
>    nautilus -q
>    ```

Comment: Useful, but this is a workaround, but not a real answer...

Comment: It is an answer that fixed it.

Answer (score 22):

Please type in Terminal:

```
sudo killall nautilus && (nautilus &)
```

Done.
This has reported here: [Nautilus does not start](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1569970)

Comment: really helping and more fine solution for me )

Comment: I also have to do this from time to time, whenever nautilus stops working.

Comment: Right, this is temporarily fixes only

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the following: I could open nautilus with

```
sudo nautilus
```

So then I killed all nautilus processes:

```
ps aux | grep nautilus
sudo kill <PID>
```

Tried:

```
nautilus -q
```

And got:

```
(nautilus:4918): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/user/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied
```

So I checked permitions of each of these folders doing:

```
ls -la /home/user/ | grep .local
ls -la /home/user/.local/ | grep share
ls -la /home/user/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/ | grep home
```

And the folder home was owned by root so I did:

```
sudo chown -R user:user /home/user/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home
```