# Can't open folders/files on my system

Tags: nautilus

I am unable to open any files/folders on my system. I was getting lots of errors while opening nautilus and I entered the following command based on [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/845016/668282).

```
sudo killall nautilus && (nautilus &)
```

After this, I am unable to even right click on the desktop and not even select any files on the desktop. There are 2 or 3 similar questions on this site regarding this issue, but none of them have been answered.

What can I do?

EDIT: As asked in the comments, this is what I get when I run the 'nautilus' command:

```
(nautilus:2399): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed

(nautilus:2399): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed

(nautilus:2399): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(nautilus:2399): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(nautilus:2399): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
```

Comment: Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: just did it now. Thanks @AndroidDev Thankfully, the desktop icons work. But when I run 'nautilus' on the terminal, it shows up a bunch of errors, opens the home folder and closes it as soon as I click somewhere else :/

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and add the full output from `nautilus` in the terminal?

Comment: @ByteCommander question edited

Comment: This is the type of warnings that we are getting used to seeing in the terminal after starting any GUI program, unfortunately. Even when marked "CRITICAL" they don't mean there is actually something wrong. "...opens the home folder and closes it as soon as I click somewhere else" sounds like the default behaviour. Can you get the window back with ALT+TAB? Or is the terminal command finished, and do you get the prompt back?

Comment: @Jos No. Alt+Tab doesn't get the window back. It automatically closes itself. Are those "CRITICAL" errors a bug in the OS? because they are kind of annoying :/