# Permissions denied while trying simple copy and paste

Tags: permissions, root, audacious

I recently wanted to add a skin to Audacious, but when I went to add the skins files to the skins folder I was denied the action. Was greeted with 
*"You are not the owner. You can not modify this folder"*

I thought root had these privileges? Wasn't I automatically made the admin of my laptop when I installed Ubuntu? I am logged in to the admin account, not as a guest.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that by root you meant your account. `root` is a separate account which has the highest level privileges. You can switch to root by doing `su`. However, the preferred choice is to use the `sudo` command which is much less dangerous.

If you have some experience with terminal, try

```
sudo cp <origin> <destination>
```

Else open the terminal and type

```
sudo -H nautilus
```

This will open a file explorer with root privileges.

16.04 appears to have a problem with running nautilus from the terminal under sudo. Installing `nautilus-admin` is a great workaround for that.

Comment: You should not start graphical applications as root at all, especially not with plain `sudo`. See e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications . There is a Nautilus extension package called `nautilus-admin` though which adds a context menu option for opening a folder or editing a file as root easily and rather safely. It can be installed e.g. using `sudo apt install nautilus-admin`.

Comment: Got Nautilus with root permissions to run....once. Now when I invoke with terminal I get the following:                                                                                 
meshica7@meshica7-MacBookPro:~$ sudo -i nautilus /home/$USER
[sudo] password for meshica7:       

(nautilus:6317): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed

(nautilus:6317): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed
Failed to register: Timeout was reached

Comment: Could you give more information about the distro you're using?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS..default DE

Comment: Install nautilus-admin with `sudo apt-get install nautilus-admin`, close all the available nautilus windows and then restart nautilus. It should work.

Comment: @JuanLeon apparently this is an open [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1569970). A workaround has been suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/788182/nautilus-not-opening-up-showing-glib-error)

Comment: Just got around to replying..sorry! Thanx! work around..well..worked!

Answer (score 1):

You are logged in as an account with root permissions available, but not enabled.

You can enable the permissions if you need, normally via the `sudo` command.

However, the `sudo` command is dangerous - there are no protections left once you run it. If you tell it to delete everything by mistake, it will.

To copy the files graphically, run this:

```
sudo -i nautilus /home/$USER
```

And move them to where they need to be. To copy  with the command line use this:

```
cp "/current/location" "/new/location"
```