# Accidentally denied access to my root folder

Tags: boot

I have a dual boot windows-ubuntu system. I accidentally denied all access to the root folder and everything went black. I tried booting from a live usb, and modifying back the read and write permissions. However even now, I still can't access my system. It halts after the disk check, and I can't even switch to another TTY. I'm completely locked out of my system. I also hid the grub menu so the recovery mode isn't available either. Anyone has an idea how to proceed from here? Or what can I do .

[edit]

ubuntu version : 20.04 LTS

for denying and regaining access I used the Nautilus file manager as root, using sudo nautilus

Comment: *for denying and regaining access I used the Nautilus file manager as root, using sudo nautilus* How exactly? And, of course, never again run graphical apps with sudo as is.

Comment: Should have used `nautilus-admin` not `nautilus`. See comments under [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/916543/348964)

Comment: anyone has an idea? it's stuck on /dev/sda6 : clean xxx files, xxx blocks

Comment: Time for a full re install of the OS.

Comment: would i lose my data ? apps ? config ?

Comment: You restore your data from your backups & your backup should include an export of the list of installed apps to make it easy to reinstall them. Your /home has all your data & user configuration in hidden files. Unless you also have data in other partitions. From live installer you may be able to backup data, if you do not have that. And you may be able to chroot into system to get list of apps. UEFI chroot, must include ESP - efi system partition
http://askubuntu.com/questions/53578/can-i-install-in-uefi-mode-with-the-alternate-installer/57380#57380

Comment: You are able to boot from usb drive. That's good news, but there's a problem on /dev/sda6?  Instead of running **fsck**, please tell us what data you can get from the **fdisk -l /dev/sda** command.  Please revise your question with the commands you've run and its output.

Comment: Also, run **fdisk -l **  and **blkid**.  Please revise your question with the commands you've run and its output.