# nautilus not opening showing the following error when I tried to open through terminal

Tags: 16.04, gnome, nautilus

```
(nautilus:6104): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed

(nautilus:6104): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed
Could not register the application: Timeout was reached

(nautilus:6104): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(nautilus:6104): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(nautilus:6104): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
```

Comment: Does nautilus work in the guest or root accounts?

Comment: Yes I can open it with sudo and root, but not with the user account until I restart.

Comment: How about the guest account? With the normal account, a restart fixes the problem? Do you know how to fsck your disk?

Comment: What's the output of `find ~ ! \( -user "$USER" -readable -writable \) -ls`?

Comment: Helo David, I can see all the files and folder and have proper permission
====Output====
4851585      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 me me       15 Jul 24 01:19 /home/godfather/.mozilla/firefox/s443rnmx.default/lock -> 127.0.1.1:+4823
  4867582     32 -rw-r--r--   1 root      root         32768 Jul  2 00:14 /home/godfather/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home-f59df3251.log

Comment: Hi, @heynnema I can open it with the guest account and yes restart fixes the problem but nautilus cause to hang and I try with sudo it works fine. This problem is hard to debug ... :) for a newbie like me

Comment: Is Nautilus in your `Startup Applications`? Did you try the fix highlighted at the top of your question?

Comment: @heynnema, Hi, I searched but nautilus in not in my startup applications and  I checked in gnome-disk-utility, it is showing that disk is fine. I think fsck is to used on corrupted disk to fix right?

Comment: fsck is a file system check. But I don't think you have a problem there. Did you try the fix they called out?

Comment: Thanks guys got the answer here, https://askubuntu.com/questions/788182/nautilus-not-opening-up-showing-glib-error/845016